# Input data into dynamic generated rows in mysqli php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on the inventory project and I want to insert product data into dynamically generated row using ajax.I successfully generating the new rows but in the generated rows the data isn't retrieving from database.In the brief I want following things-

1. In the out-stocks section user will be able to add more than one items by expanding the row
2. Items will be show in the drop down field and when users select the products then it will automatic fill the respective fields of the form
3. And its also calculate the total amount .
4. And finally submit data into database.

[Below is the form image where add and remove row button work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl8DU.png)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="php_action/createTransfer.php" id="createTransferForm">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="transDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Transfer Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="transDate" name="transDate" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
          </div> <!--/form-group-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Client's Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientName" name="clientName" placeholder="Client Name" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
          </div> <!--/form-group-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientContact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Client's Contact</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientContact" name="clientContact" placeholder="Contact Number" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
          </div> <!--/form-group-->           

          
                      <table class="table table-bordered" id="productTable">  
                               <thead>
                <tr>                        
                    <th style="width:40%;">Product</th>
                    <th style="width:20%;">Rate</th>
                    <th style="width:10%;">Available Quantity</th>
                    <th style="width:15%;">Quantity</th>                        
                    <th style="width:25%;">Items Total</th>                     
                    <th style="width:10%;"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                            <?php
                $arrayNumber = 0;
                for($x = 1; $x < 2; $x++) { ?>
                    <tr id="row<?php echo $x; ?>" class="<?php echo $arrayNumber; ?>">                          
                        <td style="margin-left:20px;">
                                     <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">

                            <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="productName[]" id="productName<?php echo $x; ?>" onchange="getProductData(<?php echo $x; ?>)"  data-live-search="true">
                                <option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>
                                <?php
                                    $productSql = "SELECT * FROM inv_product WHERE active = 1 AND status = 1 AND quantity != 0";
                                    $productData = $connect->query($productSql);

                                    while($row = $productData->fetch_array()) {                                         
                                        echo "<option value='".$row['product_id']."' id='changeProduct".$row['product_id']."'>".$row['product_name']."</option>";
                                        } // /while 

                                ?>          
                            </select>
                            </div></td>
                 <td style="padding-left:20px;">                                
                            <input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off" disabled="true" class="form-control" />                              
                            <input type="hidden" name="rateValue[]" id="rateValue<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />                              
                        </td> 
                 <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
                                <p id="available_quantity<?php echo $x; ?>" class="btn btn-info"></p>
                            </div>
                        </td>  
                 <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
                            <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity<?php echo $x; ?>" onkeyup="getTotal(<?php echo $x ?>)" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" min="1" />
                            </div>
                        </td>  
                  <td style="padding-left:20px;">                               
                            <input type="text" name="total[]" id="total<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" disabled="true" />                                
                            <input type="hidden" name="totalValue[]" id="totalValue<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />                                
                        </td>
                        <td>                                                    
                                     <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td> 
                                     <?php
                $arrayNumber++;
                } // /for
                ?>
                                     </tbody>   
                                </tr>  
                           </table>
          <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 85%;margin-right: 50px;">
            <label for="totalItemsValue">Total Values</label>
            <input type="text" name="totalItemsValue" class="form-control" id="totalItemsValue" disabled>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group submitButtonFooter">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" id="createOrderBtn" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Save Changes</button>

              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" onclick="resetOrderForm()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i> Reset</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

here is javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var i=1;  
  $('#add').click(function(){
  var tableLength = $("#productTable tbody tr").length;

var tableRow;
var arrayNumber;
var count;

if(tableLength > 0) {       
    tableRow = $("#productTable tbody tr:last").attr('id');
    arrayNumber = $("#productTable tbody tr:last").attr('class');
    count = tableRow.substring(3);  
    count = Number(count) + 1;
    arrayNumber = Number(arrayNumber) + 1;                  
} else {
    // no table row
    count = 1;
    arrayNumber = 0;
            }
         i++;  
       $('#productTable').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td> <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="productName[]" id="productName'+i+'"><option value="">~~SELECT~~</option><td style="padding-left:20px;"><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate'+i+'" autocomplete="off" disabled="true" class="form-control"/><input type="hidden" name="rateValue[]" id="rateValue'+i+'" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" /></td><td style="padding-left:40px;"><div class="form-group"><p id="available_quantity'+i+'" class="btn btn-info"></p></div></td><td style="padding-left: 35px;padding-right: 30px;"><div class="form-group"><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity'+i+'" onkeyup="getTotal('+i+')" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" min="1" /></div></td><td style="padding-left:20px;"><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total'+i+'" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" disabled="true" />    <input type="hidden" name="totalValue[]" id="totalValue'+i+'" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });  
  $('#submit').click(function(){            
       $.ajax({
    url: 'php_action/fetchProductData.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response) {
        $("#add").button("reset");          

        var tr = '<tr id="row'+count+'" class="'+arrayNumber+'">'+                          
            '<td>'+
                '<div class="form-group">'+

                '<select class="form-control selectpicke" name="productName[]" id="productName'+count+'" onchange="getProductData('+count+')" >'+
                    '<option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>';
                    // console.log(response);
                    $.each(response, function(index, value) {
                        tr += '<option value="'+value[0]+'">'+value[1]+'</option>';                         
                    });
                                                
                tr += '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td style="padding-left:20px;"">'+
                '<input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate'+count+'" autocomplete="off" disabled="true" class="form-control" />'+
                '<input type="hidden" name="rateValue[]" id="rateValue'+count+'" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />'+
            '</td style="padding-left:20px;">'+
            '<td style="padding-left:20px;">'+
                '<div class="form-group">'+
                '<p id="available_quantity'+count+'"></p>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td style="padding-left:20px;">'+
                '<div class="form-group">'+
                '<input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity'+count+'" onkeyup="getTotal('+count+')" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" min="1" />'+
                '</div>'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td style="padding-left:20px;">'+
                '<input type="text" name="total[]" id="total'+count+'" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" disabled="true" />'+
                '<input type="hidden" name="totalValue[]" id="totalValue'+count+'" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<button class="btn btn-default removeProductRowBtn" type="button" onclick="removeProductRow('+count+')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>';
        if(tableLength > 0) {                           
            $("#productTable tbody tr:last").after(tr);
        } else {                
            $("#productTable tbody").append(tr);
        }       

    } // /success
});  
  });
```

Please give me suggestions

Comment: What's your question about all this code? Anything not working yet? Please clarify your problem

Comment: Respect sir I want to retrieve data from database into dynamically generated form field of product name in the form of drop-down method and when I select product from drop-down field it's auto fill the related field i.e. price,available quantities

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. "I want" is not a question. Which kind of "suggestion" are you looking for?

Comment: _"but in the generated rows the data isn't retrieving from database"_ - well why should it? I don't see you set a single `value` attribute there to pre-populate any of the text fields, and for the select options, I don't see you output `selected` on any of them either. So - did you expect this to happen by sheer magic, or what?